# Get Custom Relationship Object's Name instead of Id into a List

Tags: apex, custom-object, relationships

I have a custom relationship to campaign object from opportunity object. When I am doing this:

```
List<sObject> opportunities = [SELECT Name, Campaign__r.Name FROM Opportunity];
for (Integer i = 0; i < opportunities.size(); i++) {
    System.debug(opportunities.get(i));
}
```

I am getting campaign object's id instead of campaign's name.

```
USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|Opportunity:{Name=Test, Campaign__c=70163000000HcFbAAK, Id=00663000008E7JuAAK}
```

How can I get campaign's name (which in my case is campaigntest) instead of campaign__c id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following to get the field value see the sobject methods [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

```
List<sObject> opportunities = [SELECT Name, Campaign__r.Name FROM Opportunity];

for (Integer i = 0; i < opportunities.size(); i++) {
    opportunit o = (opportunity) opportunities[i];
    String cName = o.Campaign__r.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug an `SObject` entire, you have little control over what is displayed. If you instead wish to display the value from a particular field path, debug specifically that field path.

```
for (Opportunity record : [SELECT Campaign__r.Name FROM Opportunity])
{
    system.debug(opportunities[i].Campaign__r.Name);
}
```

There is no reason here to assign your query to `List<SObject>`. Rather, assign it to the more specific `List<Opportunity>` type and your code will be much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your aim isn't simply to debug, but if it was, it is worth being aware of this approach (for *temporary* debugging only as this is circumventing measures the platform takes to keep debug output costs limited):

```
List<sObject> opportunities = [SELECT Name, Campaign__r.Name FROM Opportunity];

System.debug('opportunities=\n' + JSON.serializePretty(opportunities));
```

that outputs all the objects and all the fields into the debug log.